# Setting UITableView in Navigation Controller using Story Boards

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I am using storyboards to add a tableview inside a navigation-controller. TableView is currently taking all the space in it's parents view and i am unable to change the size using dragging feature in storyboard.

I actually want to adda label under the tableview which will show some static text, I want table view to arrange such that i will not cove the complete height of its parent's view.

Can you please guide me in that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should not add a tableView to a navigation controller - you should add it to the rootViewController of the Navigation Controler.

Just to confirm:
If you are using a UITableViewController, its full screen by default. In order to to change the size you need to use a UIViewController and add a UITableView. This way you will be able to resize hope this helps.

UINavigationController -> RootViewController(Add a UITableView to this)

N.B. If you create a UINavigationController its rootViewController is a UITableViewController by default. Delete this add a UIViewController.

[image: StoryBoard]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with a UITableView in a storyboard.

Instead, what you can do is create the label in your ViewDidLoad function and then add it to the UITableView as the tableView's tableHeaderView.

example:

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 44)]];
  label.text = @"My static text";
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = label;    
}
```